# Adding routes for configured virtual IP addresses of different segments

Tags: rhel, ip, routing

I have configured virtual IP addresses in different segments as below in RHEL box.

eth0 - 192.X.X.208/27
eth0:1 - 192.X.X.219/27
eth0:2 - 10.72.X.19/24
eth0:3- 10.72.X.20/24

The problem here is as soon as i bring up these interfaces, the network goes unreachable. I believe there a route has to be added to solve this.. How can this be done??

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this about a year ago(2 nics, 2 networks, 2 routes).  I haven't done it with 2 networks in the same nic, but here's the instructions I followed:

http://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/

Comment: Thanks AITMVanorder ... But i am looking for plumbing all these IP's under single NIC as already stated. I believe we have work to do on the network switch as well.

Comment: If you're able to split the traffic between 2 vlans you could use one physical nic, but the your interfaces would be eth0.2 eth0.2:0 wth0.3 eth0.3:0.  this would be 2 interfaces to the OS with 2 aliases, but one physical nic.